# Does one player buying a lot of Lumiose Galettes affect another buying them?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Does the stand have a limited number of items or it's just that they only sell them at certain times? Or, to be clear, do Lumiose Galettes actually sell out?

Because sometimes I have tried to buy some at 09:13 and got a response that they were sold out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lumiose_City#Galette_Stand):

> The stand only sells freshly baked galettes, which last four hours at a time starting at 3 AM, 9 AM, 3 PM, and 9 PM. Once per day, if the player purchases a galette within an hour of the time they were baked, the player will also receive a free Moomoo Milk.